# How to add an additional button to a column header (extjs 6.2)

Tags: extjs, extjs6.2

**i need to add a button to the column header besides the filters menu** (like the blue mark on the photo)

[image: button where's the blue mark]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little hack like this could work. Just get the layout aligned to show content in left and right most parts of Container.

```
Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
layout: 'fit',

items: [{
    xtype: 'container',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'grid',
        sortable: true,
        columns: [{
            flex: 1
        }, {
            text: "Age",
            flex: 1
        }],
        listeners: {
            afterrender: function (grid) {
                var columns = grid.columnManager.getColumns();
                var nameCol = columns[0];
                var targetDom = nameCol.textInnerEl.dom;
                var newPanel = Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'label',
                        text: "Name"
                    }, {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: "DO IT"
                    }],
                    renderTo: targetDom
                   });
               }
           }
        }]
   }]
});
```

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/29o8